# Is there an approximate version of the strong duality theorem for linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, primal-dual

Consider the following dual linear programs:
$$
\min \mathbf{c^T x} ~~ \text{s.t.} ~~ A \mathbf{x} \geq \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{x}\geq 0;
\\
\max \mathbf{b^T y} ~~ \text{s.t.} ~~ A^T \mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{y}\geq 0.
$$
By the strong duality theorem, if there is an optimal solution $\mathbf{y^*}$ to the dual problem, then the primal problem has an optimal solution $\mathbf{x^*}$ with $\mathbf{c^T x^*} = \mathbf{b^T y^*}$.

Suppose now that the dual problem is very large, and I can solve it only approximately. Specifically, I can find a vector $\mathbf{y'}$ such that:

- $A^T \mathbf{y'} \leq (1+\epsilon)\cdot \mathbf{c}$ - the constraints are only approximately satisfied;
- $\mathbf{b^T y'} \geq \mathbf{b^T y}$ for any vector $\mathbf{y}$ that satisfies the original constraints $\mathbf{y} \leq \mathbf{c}$.

So $\mathbf{y'}$ is optimal for the original constraints, but it may violate these constraints a bit.

QUESTION: Can I draw from this, any conclusion regarding the optimal (or approximately-optimal) solution of the primal LP?

NOTE: It is easy to prove a variant of the weak duality theorem for this setting. If $\mathbf{x}$ is any feasible solution to the primal, then:

$$
\mathbf{c^T x} = \mathbf{x^T c} \geq 
\\
\geq \mathbf{x^T}\cdot A^T\mathbf{y'}/(1+\epsilon)
\\
= (A\mathbf{x})^T\cdot \mathbf{y'}/(1+\epsilon)
\\
\geq \mathbf{b^T y'}/(1+\epsilon).
$$

So a candidate for a variant of the strong duality theorem is: the primal LP has a solution $\mathbf{x^*}$ for which:
$$
\mathbf{b^T y'} \cdot (1+\epsilon) \geq \mathbf{c^T x^*} \geq b^T \mathbf{y'}/(1+\epsilon)
$$
Is this true?

If so, is there an algorithm for finding such $\mathbf{x^*}$, given the vector $\mathbf{y'}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A candidate for a variant of the strong duality theorem is: the primal LP has a solution $\mathbf{x^*}$ for which:
> $$
> \mathbf{b^T y'} \cdot (1+\epsilon) \geq \mathbf{c^T x^*} \geq b^T \mathbf{y'}/(1+\epsilon)
> $$
> Is this true?

**The answer is yes** (assuming the optimal solution has non-negative cost, e.g. $c\ge \mathbf 0$), simply by strong duality.  Let $(x^*, y^*)$ be an optimal primal-dual pair.  Then

1. $c \cdot x^* = b\cdot y^* \le b\cdot y' \le (1+\epsilon) b\cdot y'$ (by your assumption on $y'$, and $b\cdot y^*\ge 0$), and
2. $c\cdot x^* \ge b\cdot y'/(1+\epsilon)$ (by weak duality, as you point out, as $y'/(1+\epsilon)$ is a feasible dual solution)

So, in this case, technically, this $x^*$ answers your question affirmatively.

(I assume you don't intend to consider the case that the optimal cost is negative, because this case requires $c \not\ge \mathbf 0$, and then your condition $A^T y' \le (1+\epsilon) c$ is not actually a relaxation of $A^T y' \le c$.)

> Is there an algorithm for finding such $x^*$ given $y'$?

**The answer is yes.**  One can compute $x^*$ (given $y'$, or not) in poly-time by solving the LP.

**Okay, but is there a faster way?**  No, not in general.
Even having an optimal feasible dual solution does not always make it easy to compute an approximately optimal primal solution.
Consider any primal problem of the form
$$\min \{ 0 : Ax\ge b, x\ge 0\}.$$
The problem of finding an optimal or approximately optimal primal solution is equivalent to the problem of finding a *feasible* primal solution, as $c=\mathbf 0$.
Assuming the primal is feasible, the dual solution $y = \mathbf 0$ is optimal, and gives no information about how to find the primal solution.

For a concrete example, consider the problem of finding a perfect matching in a given bipartite graph $G$.  This can be formulated in the above form, as $\min \{c\cdot x : Ax\ge b, x\ge 0\}$ with $c = \mathbf 0$, using a variable $x_e\ge 0$ for each edge $e$, and encoding the perfect-matching constraints $(\forall v) \sum_{e \text{ inc } v} x_e = 1$ in the matrix constraints $Ax\ge b$, as $B x \ge 1$ and $-Bx \ge -1$ where $B_v x = \sum_{e\text{ inc } v} x_e$.  If $G$ has a perfect matching, then the dual solution $y_v = 0$ is optimal, and gives no information about how to compute any feasible (and therefore optimal or approximately optimal) perfect matching.

Comment: I do wonder about the special case of packing and covering, that is, when all entries of $A$ are non-negative.